# How can I continue writing to a file after clearing it?

Tags: java, printwriter

I'm trying to:

-Take the contents of a file (called list.txt), modify it and submit into a tempfile (listtemp.txt).

-Clear list.txt, print the new contents of listtemp.txt into list.txt, then clear the listtemp.txt for further modifying of list.txt

The problem is, when I have the appropriate contents in listtemp.txt, I can't take the new contents and put it in the list.txt. I successfully clear the list, but then I can't append or write to the list using a PrintWriter.

I've tried clearing the list.txt using FileWriter, setting the parameter to false to clear it, then closing the FileWriter, and using my original PrintWriter that I use to print/append directly to my list.txt.

I've tried completely deleting list.txt, then recreating it, then using the original PrintWriter to print/append again, directly print/append the text file.

So as said before, I modify the list.txt and put it in a listtemp.txt successfully. Then I tried creating a swapListing() method to clear list.txt and add the contents of listtemp.txt.

```
    private void swapListing() {


        FileWriter fw = null; //This is the temporary FileWriter to clear the text file
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(main.file, false); //Main list is cleared.
            fw.close();
            fw = null;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            String temp = main.getReader().readFile(main.filetemp); //I got the contents of the String from my listtemp.txt, and I checked, and the String is successfully retrieved, so this isn't the problem.
            pwriter.print(temp); // This is where I feel like file SHOULD be appended
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I tried deleting the file as well, but the file doesn't actually get deleted, and the original content also in fact is still in the file.

```
    private void clearFile() {
        if (main.file.exists()) {
            main.file.delete();
            try {
                main.file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            String temp = main.getReader().readFile(main.filetemp);
            pwriter.print(temp);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I would prefer not to use the delete file method, but at this point I would just like a working solution that I can at least use.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of "safe saving" and it even has special support by operating systems (at least on Windows). The procedure is:

- don't touch the original file
- save all data into a new temporary file
- delete the original file
- move the temporary file to the original place

The operating system will then apply the timestamps of the original file for you. Moving a file on the same disk is a very fast operation. The necessary modification is only in the file system structure. The file content stays on the exact same place on disk.

You are not following this procedure. To me it sounds overly complex to

- save a part of the data into a new temporary file
- clear / delete the original file
- read the whole file into memory again
- write it back to the original file
- write more data into the original file

You have not stated how and when you create the `pwriter`. Does it use a `BufferedWriter`? When does it get closed? Does it get closed at all? If not, do you `flush()` it? If so, when? If not, that might be a part of the problem.